# Changing alpha of UITableView without affecting header

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a header through `tableHeaderView`. For an animation I am working on, I am trying to change the alpha of the table part of the UITableView without changing the alpha of the header. As expected, something as simple as `tableView.alpha = 0`, changes the alpha of the whole thing. Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the alpha of UITableViewCell. Just place cell.alpha = 0.0f; in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITableView. It will not affect the header.